# confuse with 'this' keyword in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

Please help, I couldn't figure this out.

```
function Tour(el) {
  var tour = this;
  this.el = el;
  this.fetchPhotos = function() { 
    $.ajax('/photos.html', {
      data: {location: tour.el.data('location')},
      context: tour,
      success: function(response) {
        this.el.find('.photos').html(response).fadeIn();
      },
      error: function() {
        this.el.find('.photos').html('<li>There was a problem fetching the latest photos. Please try again.</li>');
      },
      timeout: 3000,
      beforeSend: function() {
        this.el.addClass('is-fetching');
      },
      complete: function() {
        this.el.removeClass('is-fetching');
      }
    });
  }
  this.el.on('click', 'button', this.fetchPhotos);
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var paris = new Tour($('#paris'));
});
```

in the function above, I know the `context: tour` sets `this` inside the `this.fetchPhotos` function to reference Tour. So my question is why can this part of code `tour.el.data('location')` change to `this.el.data('location')`?

Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: Read [this](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) .

Comment: you are losing context of `this` within `$.ajax`, declare as a different variable outside `$.ajax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that works is because `tour.el.data('location')` is called from `fetchPhotos`.

As long as you do

```
new Tour().fetchPhotos();
```

and not

```
var f = new Tour().fetchPhotos;
f();
```

the replacement will work.

But doing

```
this.el.on('click', 'button', this.fetchPhotos);
```

is like the latter. It does not work the same.

Comment: To expand a little: a rule of thumb is, that the context is whatever is on the left side of the dot when the function is called. `this.fetchPhotos` doesn't call the method, instead one could imagine it to happen like this: `var callback = arguments[2]; callback.call(that, args);` where `that === el`.

Comment: @Derija93, good explanation for an often poorly explained concept.

Answer (score 0):

As charlietfl wrote, this is a different context inside ajax callbacks, you have to cache `this` to any variable before ajax call and use that variable. Like you did in `tour` variable:

```
function Tour(el) {
  var tour = this;
  this.el = el;
  this.fetchPhotos = function() { 
    $.ajax('/photos.html', {
      data: {location: tour.el.data('location')},
      context: tour,
      success: function(response) {
        tour.el.find('.photos').html(response).fadeIn();
      },
      error: function() {
        tour.el.find('.photos').html('<li>There was a problem fetching the latest photos. Please try again.</li>');
      },
      timeout: 3000,
      beforeSend: function() {
        tour.el.addClass('is-fetching');
      },
      complete: function() {
        tour.el.removeClass('is-fetching');
      }
    });
  }
  this.el.on('click', 'button', this.fetchPhotos);
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var paris = new Tour($('#paris'));
});
```

Outside of the ajax call (like the click event binder) it is ok to use `this`, but in those callback functions, it refers to that callback handler